# Apache - Rewrite rule changes URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my .htaccess file, I have

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(swf|gif|jpe?g|png|css|txt|js|json|xml|ico)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

If I have a directory called `myfiles` and in the browser address bar I go to `http://localhost/mysite/myfiles/` everything is fine, but if I go to `http://localhost/mysite/myfiles` (without the trailing slash), the URL in the address bar changes to `http://localhost/mysite/myfiles/?page=myfiles`

How do I change the .htaccess so that it doesn't change the URL and expose the variable? And why does it do that in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because mod_dir is redirecting requests for directories that don't end in a slash to ones that do, and there's a [very good reason why it must do this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash).

What you'll need to do is either turn off mod_dir and/or redirect those slashes yourself:

```
DirectorySlash off

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(swf|gif|jpe?g|png|css|txt|js|json|xml|ico)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: When I try your example, requesting a directory without a trailing slash results in a 404 error because it tries to get the directory in the parent parent directory of the PHP script (`http://localhost/myfiles/` instead of `http://localhost/mysite/myfiles/`).

Comment: And while I understand what DirectorySlash does, I don't understand why the URL changes in the address bar. It's the same directory with or without the trailing slash, Apache knows it's a directory, what reason does it have to show the $page variable?

Comment: Ah, I added `RewriteBase /mysite` and changed `/$1/` to `./$1/` and now it works I think